# Can't download large folders from onedrive on chromium and firefox

Tags: download, onedrive

I want to download my pictures and documents from onedrive on Linux.
However onedrive is stupidly slow (maybe because I didn't access my files for 1 year).
The zip-file download is extremely slow (Not even 1MB/s) and it takes ages until they loaded a file. After a bit of time Firefox reports a 'network error' and on Chromium it's just stuck and won't finish, not even continue retrieving any bit.

Where can I report this problem and get help quickly? Or is there a fix, script that downloads files one by one? I do not want to install Windows anymore. It's shit.

Since I do not pay anymore they'll 'freeze' my account soon (not sure what that is). Probably against the GDRP since they have to DELETE when I request and there's no such option.

Do you want to know how fast it is?
... 2MiB/s for a short time and then for an a bit longer time nothing!!

Comment: I suggest using a proper client, like Cyberduck CLI. The ZIP download uses server resources and would of course suck.

Comment: Great idea. I can't find the documentation but I remember that there's something called rclone.

Comment: Guess they did something: unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

No I just misconfigured. It's fine.

Comment: Can I report this to microsoft? If yes, where? I wonder how they reply. Currently I am using rsync to download the files. It's extremely slow!

Comment: Use https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver